# How to add and view data of a core model relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I am new to Core Data and I know how to add an read data from entities.
I have two entities:

1. Training with an attribute name: String
2. Workout with an attribute name: String

The relationships are

- Training > Workout to many optional
- Workout > Training to one !optional

In my app I want to add trainings and workouts, that are children of trainings.

After creating the entities (codegen is manual), I created the NSManagedObject subclasses automatically and didn't change them.

My `ContentView.swift` looks like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var newTrainingName: String = ""
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Training.name, ascending: true)]) var trainings: FetchedResults<Training>
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Group {
                    VStack {
                        TextField("Name", text: $newTrainingName)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(15)
                        Button(action: {
                            let training = Training(context: self.viewContext)
                            training.name = self.newTrainingName
                            try! self.viewContext.save()
                        }) {
                            Text("Add")
                                .padding()
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)))
                    .cornerRadius(15)
                }
                .padding()
                List (trainings, id: \.self) { training in
                    NavigationLink(destination: WorkoutView(training: training)) {
                        Text(training.name!)
                    }
                }
            }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Trainings"))
        }
    }
}

struct WorkoutView: View {

    var training: Training
    @State var newWorkoutText: String = ""
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Group {
                VStack {
                    TextField("Name", text: $newWorkoutText)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.white)
                        .cornerRadius(15)
                    Button(action: {
                        let workout = Workout(context: self.viewContext)
                        workout.name = self.newWorkoutText
                        self.training.addToWorkouts(workout)
                        try! self.viewContext.save()
                    }) {
                        Text("Add")
                            .padding()
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)))
                .cornerRadius(15)
            }
            .padding()
            List (training.workouts ?? [], id: \.self) { workout in
                Text(workout.name!)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

For the `ContentView()` everything is working fine. I am lost with the `WorkoutView()` part.
I want to add workouts to trainings in Core Data and display them.

Within the `Training+CoreDataProperties.swift` I changed

```
@NSManaged public var workouts: NSSet?
```

to

```
@NSManaged public var workouts: [Workout]?
```

because I thought it makes sense. But this is still part of losing myself.

Additionally I found this autogenerated code, that looks right, but I don't know how to use it in my code:

```
// MARK: Generated accessors for workouts
extension Training {

    @objc(addWorkoutsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToWorkouts(_ value: Workout)

    @objc(removeWorkoutsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromWorkouts(_ value: Workout)

    @objc(addWorkouts:)
    @NSManaged public func addToWorkouts(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeWorkouts:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromWorkouts(_ values: NSSet)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have setup the relationship in Core Data, as in the .xcdatamodelid, including the inverse relationship.

I would also recommend a do catch instead of `try!` for a better UI.

your relationship in core data should look like this:

in Training Entity:
Relationship: Workouts,
Destination: Workout,
Inverse: training

in Workout Entity:
Relationship: Training,
Destination: Training,
Inverse: workout

you should be able to just do this in your button action:

```
    let workout = Workout(context: self.viewContext)
    workout.name = self.newWorkoutText
    workout.training = self.training
    do {
      try self.viewContext.save()
    } catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: When I read that correctly, this will create I training, not a workout, didn't it?

Comment: no this will create a workout with an association to training.

Comment: okay. How can I list that results that are related to training? My Code is not working and causes `Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate` on the first VStack. Additionally training.workouts is NSSet

Answer (score -1):

Where is self.training.addToWorkouts(workout) coming from? That doesn't look right.

You want to add training to your workout in your WorkoutView. The relationship works just like any attribute so just assign training to it with =

Comment: New users cannot post comments to a question. Moreover, there is an answer if you read carefully